# preg_replace PHP - / ou @ , por que colocar?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Usando preg_replace() no PHP, me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```
echo preg_replace('/:([\w]+)/', 'batata', ':quiabo/isso/:nada');

echo preg_replace('@:([\w]+)@', 'batata', ':quiabo/isso/:nada');
```

Ambas expressões imprimem a mesma coisa: batata/isso/batata

A partir disso tenho duas dúvidas:

1 - Porque precisamos usar '/' ou '@' no começo da pattern?

2 - Qual a diferença entre usar '/' ou '@' nesta mesma situação?

Comment: Também pode usar `~`, acho que fica mais legível dependendo da ER.

Comment: Ou `#` ou `%`, ou `~`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Nenhuma diferença, serve apenas para indicar o inicio (delimitadores) e fim da sua regex

Update:

So no caso de voce quiser casar com um '@' ai teria que escapar usando os delimitadores @

ex.

```
@\@@
```

ou

```
/@/
```